# email with attached excel sheet in lightning/apex

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

I have requirement ,where i am searching for a record in search aura comp and if records found then i am attaching those records in Excel sheet and sending email to the user. But sending email is taking time .is there any way to send email with attachment fast.

Below is my code. user need to get email immediately but based on records its taking time.
Please suggest or any alternate way to do this

```
public static void sendData(List<Account> acList) {
 string header = 'Record Id, Name , Rating \n';
    string finalstr = header ;

    for(Account a: acList)
    {
    
           string recordString = a.id+','+a.Name+','+a.rating +'\n';
    
           finalstr = finalstr +recordString;
    
    }
    String userName = UserInfo.getUserName();
    User activeUser = [Select Email From User where Username = : userName limit 1];
    String userEmail = activeUser.Email;
 
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment csvAttc = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(finalstr);
    string csvname= 'Account.csv';
    csvAttc.setFileName(csvname);
    csvAttc.setBody(csvBlob);
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email =new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new list<string> {userEmail};
    String subject ='Account CSV';
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
    email.setPlainTextBody('Account CSV ');
    email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{csvAttc});
    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

1. You are generating a CSV file incorrectly, not an Excel sheet. They are different file formats. Your CSV-generating code is not correctly implementing [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) and will break on embedded newlines, commas, and quotes.
2. This code will take an amount of time that scales with the count of records. If you are processing a large number of records, it's possible that the user may be able to perceive the processing time, and that's to be expected.
3. Emails take a nonzero amount of time to be delivered, full stop.

To be quite frank, the alternate approach I would suggest is to throw away this implementation and tell the users to satisfy their data-access needs using built-in platform tools, such as List Views and Reports, or consider evaluating a product that directly connects Salesforce to the spreadsheet application of your choice.